# Implied do loops in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, gfortran, do-loops

How to do the same thing with implied do loops?
I want to replace the existing loop for Vcvo and Vcvonew with two implied do loops?

This is my code:

```
Program DO_LOOPS

Implicit none

Integer::i,j
Integer,parameter::BrCv=15,BrSat=24

Real,dimension(0:BrCv-1,BrSat)::Vcvo
Real,dimension(BrCv-1,BrSat)::Vcvonew

Do i=0,BrCv-1
   do j=1,BrSat

Vcvo(i,j)=i+j*BrCv/BrSat

 end do
End do

Do i=1,BrCv-1
   do j=1,BrSat


   Vcvonew(i,j)=Vcvo(i,j)

   end do
End do

Stop
End program DO_LOOPS
```

Comment: You intend that `i+j*BrCv/BrSat` is an integer expression?

Comment: To echo the comment by @Ross, what is it you really care about?  One could very easily use an implied-do in an array constructor for `vcvo` (and it's so easy, I'm not sure I understand the question), but other than making five lines one less intuitive line I don't know why an implied-do is what you care about.

Comment: I need a suggestion for Vcvonew.How to replace my solution for do loops with doubl implied do loops, for example I try with this solution but is not correct:
((Vcvonew(i,j),j=1,BrSat),i=1,BrCv-1)

Comment: Why do you need an implied-do solution over the do constructs you have or even `vcvonew=vcvo(1:,:)`?  It just isn't obvious to me that an answer of the first type is really going to be what you think it will be.

Comment: FORALL might be more sensible here.

Answer (score 3):

An implied do loop will be:

```
Vcvo = reshape([((i + j*real(BrCv)/real(Brsat), i=0,BrCv-1), j=1,Brsat)],[BrCv,BrSat])
```

for the first one.

For the second one you don't need an implied loop. A simple array assignment, as already suggested, will do:

```
Vcvonew = vcvo(1:,:)
```

The first one doesn't look to me clearer than an explicit loop. But if you want a more compact solution you can use `do concurrent`:

```
do concurrent (i = 0:BrCv-1, j=1:Brsat)
    Vcvo(i,j) = i + j*real(BrCv)/real(Brsat)
end do
```

You spare a couple of lines.

I have also taken the liberty to transform BrCv and BrSat to real before dividing them. It may not be what you want, but it is something you have pay attention.

Comment: Well yes, but it is the more logical way to write it. I update the answer to take care of your comment.